# Get time stamps from TileWMS Layer Openlayers

Tags: javascript, wms, wms-time, open-data-cube

I've got a WMS Layer which contains many different images at different times. I'm able to display in Openlayers the images from a single time period if I specify a "time" parameter in params. I've seen it's [possible to change the wms time automatically if you have a list of time values](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/wms-time.html) but was wondering if it was possible to take the time steps from the wms.

The time steps are all displayed in a WMS GetCapabilities request as well if that helps. Below is the javascript I have so far used in the OpenLayers call:

```
import Map from 'ol/Map.js';
import View from 'ol/View.js';
import TileLayer from 'ol/layer/Tile.js';
import ImageLayer from 'ol/layer/Image.js';
import OSM from 'ol/source/OSM.js';
import TileWMS from 'ol/source/TileWMS.js';
import ImageWMS from 'ol/source/ImageWMS.js';

var base_layer = new TileLayer({
  source: new OSM()
});

var dc_wms = new TileLayer({
  source: new TileWMS({
    url: 'http://localhost:5000/',
    params: {
      'LAYERS': '10DayIndices',
      'STYLE': 'ndvi',
      time: '2019-06-20'
    }
  })
});

var map = new Map({
  layers: [base_layer, dc_wms],
  target: 'map',
  view: new View({
  projection: 'EPSG:4326',
    center: [102.376126,48.031532],
    zoom: 6
  })
});
```

I can also provide more info on the GetCapabilities request (the time is in format ISO:8601) if that would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found an answer to this when searching around further today [(specifically when looking at this question)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54525164/openlayers-wms-layer-how-to-get-the-time-dimension-from-a-specific-layer), using the ol.format.WMSCapabilities() class, using the code below:

```
var url = "***my_wms_url**";

var GetCaps = new ol.format.WMSCapabilities();

fetch(url).then(function(response) {
      return response.text();
    }).then(function(text) {
      var result = GetCaps.read(text);
      var times = results.Capability.Layer.Layer[0].Dimension;
});
```